# Secure JWT tokens against "burglars"

Tags: jwt

The issue I have with JWT tokens is in the event the token is stolen. Now I have a session that is linked to the token in the back end. I do save the user's IP address when the token is first generated.

The issue is that, because of mobile phones and cellular networks, the IP can change while the end user is using the web app, so I cannot enforce an IP verification. I do a UUID check but since the UUID is passed with the token, obtaining the token also means obtaining the UUID.

Is there any way to secure JWT tokens for the case they get stolen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to protect tokens from being used by a malicious party. There is a concept of "sender-constrained tokens". These are access tokens which require the sender to present some kind of proof of possession of the token. Such a token, is no longer a bearer token, meaning that it can only be used by the original client, not by anyone who manages to steal that token. There are different way to implement sender-constrained tokens (sometimes also called proof-of-possession tokens). E.g. you can use [mTLS constraint](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-certificate-bound-access-token/), which is reliable but a bit harder to implement, or a standard called [DPoP](https://curity.io/resources/learn/dpop-overview/) - Demonstration of Proof-of-Possession. The latter one doesn't require you to deal with Public Key Infrastructure.